# Git untrack and push

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-untracked

Situation: I untrack some files keeping them locally. Files are removed from the index and kept in working tree. Then I commit and push to remote. Files will be deleted from remote repository.

What will happen to other people when they pull? Will their local file be deleted (like remote) or will they keep their local copy, untracked (like my working tree)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other people *pull* the branch locally then, their local files will be deleted like remote since the files are deleted from remote.

---

`git rm --cached` remove the file(s) from staging area, so the file(s) become untracked (not known/handle by git anymore). After Commit, Push the file is deleted from the remote.

Like if you just create a new file *a.txt* but not Add, Commit, Push to remote (a.txt is a untracked file), then *a.txt* is totally unknown to other people when pulling locally.

Comment: So adding `--cached` to `git rm` makes no difference to anyone else beside yourself.

Comment: Yes, `git rm --cached` remove the file(s) from staging area, so the file(s) become untracked (not known/handle by git anymore). After Commit, Push the file is deleted from the remote.

Comment: Like if you just create a new file `a.txt` but not Add, Commit, Push to remote (a.txt is untracked file), then `a.txt` is totally unknown to other people when pulling locally.

Comment: It's weird having an operation that behaves differently to your teammates' working trees...

Answer (score 1):

To start ignoring the changes to the file

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file
```

To start keeping track again

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file
```